Why does `<StaticResource ResourceKey="{x:Static ... }" />` not work inside a DataTemplate?
I've come across what looks like a strange edge case in WPF around what's allowed to be a nested element vs an attribute. I've got a basic WPF application, one Window and a default App.xaml.
The MainWindow class has a key defined in code behind:
public const string IntKey = nameof(IntKey);

and XAML like this:
<Window x:Class="StaticResourceTest.MainWindow"
    ...namespaces etc...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <system:Int32 x:Key="{x:Static local:MainWindow.IntKey}">1234</system:Int32>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type system:String}">
            <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource {x:Static local:MainWindow.IntKey}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <ContentControl Content="test" />
</Window>

This works - the window content tries to show a string, the DataTemplate resource intercepts it and shows another ContentControl that's showing the int 1234.
If I convert the Content attribute in the DataTemplate to a nested element, I get an exception:
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type system:String}">
            <ContentControl>
                <ContentControl.Content>
                    <StaticResource ResourceKey="{x:Static local:MainWindow.IntKey}" />
                </ContentControl.Content>
            </ContentControl>
        </DataTemplate>


Cannot find resource named 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticExtension'. Resource names are case sensitive.

If I then convert the ResourceKey attribute as well:
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type system:String}">
            <ContentControl>
                <ContentControl.Content>
                    <StaticResource>
                        <StaticResource.ResourceKey>
                            <x:Static Member="local:MainWindow.IntKey" />
                        </StaticResource.ResourceKey>
                    </StaticResource>
                </ContentControl.Content>
            </ContentControl>
        </DataTemplate>

It works again, going back to displaying 1234 in the window.
Notes

This plays out the same using a keyed DataTemplate rather than an implicit one
This error only occurs when the ContentControl is inside a DataTemplate - if I put it directly in the Window body, it works in all three cases.

The Question
Why does the first change cause an exception? Why does the second make it go away again? It looks to me like they should all be equivalent.

Why are you trying to define the x:Key of the resource using x:Static?  Why not just give it x:Key="IntKey" and be done with it?  Then you can get rid of the similar x:Static tag you used when you define the ContentControl.Content

I'm trying to avoid the use of magic strings - in the real application the definition and usage of the resource are in separate assemblies and remembering to update the strings everywhere leaves the door open for errors.
Besides, the question wasn't about "how can I avoid this issue?", it was "why does this exception happen in this particular case?"

@GiladWaisel Can you explain that a bit more? The second case has "ResourceKey=" - what conversion is taking place in that case that isn't in the other two?

Sorry for misleading with previous note that is deleted now. I have managed to fix the problem in the second case that is not working by replacing the StaticResourec with DynamicResource and it works. I assume that the resolution of the resource came before it was set. So, the dynamic resource is helping by re-fetching when it is set.

Hmm, I never used ContentControl inside of a DataTemplate, usually its the other way around, since ContentControl will look for a DataTemplate based on type, when you bind it's content property. Not sure what you are trying to achieve here since you're going against the grain. The edge case might stem from the fact that DataTemplates are not part of VisualTree which will cause some errors when trying to access some resources.

The failing code can be fixed by using DynamicResource instead of StaticResource.
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type system:String}">
                <ContentControl>
                    <ContentControl.Content>
                        <DynamicResource ResourceKey="{x:Static local:MainWindow.IntKey}" />
                    </ContentControl.Content>
                </ContentControl>
            </DataTemplate>

